# Android intent help needed

Tags: android, android-intent

I recently started android. I came across the `putExtra(key,value)` method in the `Intent` class. I don't understand what is the use of key parameter.

I want to pass string value to the other activity. Please help me to exoplain the code. I am using from [Android Developer Portal](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Key is used to retrieve data from the second Activity. For example, in the following code snippet you are using YOUR_KEY as a string while sending data along with intent bundle.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
String message = editText.getText().toString();
intent.putExtra("YOUR_KEY", message);
startActivity(intent);
```

In Activity2, you can retrieve the values using

```
String message = intent.getStringExtra("YOUR_KEY");
```